# Means for measuring hand tremors using simple analog IC

Tags: analog, gyro, gyroscope

To measure potential dietary improvements, I want to measure how steady a person can hold their hand.
I will use a simple lightbar 0-10 LED indicator (peak volume style.) An op-amp configured for sample and hold over a set period of time, with the accumulated output voltage being displayed by the light bar. Output voltage will be dependent on inertial changes over a period of time.

What I need is a way to turn even the finest of tremors into an output voltage. Any inertial changes should output a voltage that is dependent on the amount of the tremor. I'm confident in producing the needed circuit, but I'm struggling with how to acquire the measurement of the tremor.

Comment: An accelerometer?

Comment: What survey work of the existing scholarly material have you already done? There are articles on the topic of `motion characteristics` and [`classifications`](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8350038/), for example. There are also papers on [methods](https://clinicaltrials.gov/study/NCT02641366?term=hand%20tremors&page=3&rank=30). You should be telling us a great deal about what exactly needs to be measured. You don't need to say how. But you do need to say exactly what motions and where on the hand they occur and with what dynamic range of magnitude. You are the expert. Not us.

Comment: Where will the sensor be located? Can it be on the person's wrist? Smart watches have accelerometers, this could be a software exercise.

Comment: A theremin can translate hand tremors to pitch - maintaining constant pitch is a difficult task. Pitch period can be measured easily, with good accuracy.

Comment: An accelerometeris the obvious solution. If you want to measure extremely tiny movements, maybe something like an optical lever (or even a ballistic lever).